# shared-mailbox created in Exchange - auto reply and text

Tags: exchange, sharing, mailbox, auto-reply

Does anybody know if this is possible for a Shared-mailbox created in Exchange?

Can we make sure that the customer receives the email in the return reply that the customer has sent to us? The customer now "only" receive the auto-reply that we have created under auto-reply

So I want to setup the orginal email within the autoreply?

I tried using the Outlook settings from the OWA but I can't find any solution

Comment: Could you please provide more details on your requirement?  
Not understand why the auto-reply cannot meet your need...

Comment: Hi Yuki. I have a shared mailbox that has an auto reply. When people sent to this shared mailbox they get the auto reply. But is it possible to setup the orginal text that the customer sent to the sharedmailbox with the auto reply? So they get the auto reply and the orginal e-mail that they have sent?

Answer (score 0):

So you want the original email to be included in the auto reply, right? If this is the case, it's not feasible right now using the native features in either Exchange or Outlook.

From the perspective of Outlook client side, however, in theory you can follow the steps below:

1. Add the shared mailbox as an account in Outlook (Authenticate using the credential of a user who have full access to the shared mailbox. Refer to [this link](https://www.michev.info/blog/post/3567/how-to-add-a-shared-mailbox-as-additional-account-in-outlook-2022-version) for details. ).
2. Refer to the link below to use Outlook VBA codes for your need: Outlook VBA codes

[How to Auto Reply with the Original Email and a Predefined Text via Outlook VBA](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/auto-reply-original-email-predefined-text-via-outlook-vba/)

But please be aware that, as indicated in the linked article above, this method can only make effects when the Outlook is running. So, seems to me that it's not practical as keeping the Outlook running all the time is not that realistic.

With the above being said, I'd recommend posting it to the official feedback portal as well to request this feature.
https://aka.ms/ExchangeServerFeedback

Comment: Hi Yuki! thank you for the post. Another question. Do you know if its possible to setup a standard mail signature when sending an e-mail from a shared mailbox? Or do I have to manually add the signature everytime i will send an email from the shared mailbox?

Comment: Guess you are using on-prem Exchange, right? If this is the case, it's not possible unless you and all other users of the shared mailbox add the shared mailbox as an additional account in Outlook (As mentioned in step1 above). In this way, you can add signatures for the shared mailbox the same way as your primary mailbox. Another option is to create a transport rule from Exchange server side to add disclaimer as the signature for mails sent from the shared mailbox. This could be the better choice.